# How to use substitution to solve a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

For this question, I'm stuck on how to implement a substitution. Can anyone help me out?

$(\sin(y)-y\sin(x))dx + (x\cos(y)+\cos(x))dy = 0 $

Comment: Oh so this is basically like finding the potential function?

Answer (score 1):

This is an exact differential equation. An exact differential equation is an equation of the form:

$$P(x,y)dx +Q(x,y)dy=0 $$

where $P(x,y),Q(x,y)$ are $C^2$ (twice continuously differentiable) functions and we satisfy:

$$\cfrac{\partial P(x,y)}{\partial y}=\cfrac{\partial Q(x,y)}{\partial x}$$

We check that indeed:

$$\cfrac{\partial (\sin(y)-y\sin(x))}{\partial y}= \cos(y)-\sin(x)=\cfrac{\partial  (x\cos(y)+\cos(x))}{\partial x}$$

It is also clear that $P$ and $Q$ are also $C^2$, as $\sin$ and $\cos$ are actually $C^{\infty}$.

To solve, we can either solve a system of PDEs, given by the above condition, or calculate a line integral (integrating both sides of the equation, of course):

$$\Psi(x,y)=\int P(x,y)dx +Q(x,y)dy= \int (\sin(y)-y\sin(x))dx+(x\cos(y)+\cos(x))dy \implies$$

$$\Psi(x,y)=x\sin(y)+y\cos(x)=C$$

where I "absorb" the multiplier by $2$ into the arbitrary constant $C$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(\sin(y)-y\sin(x))dx + (x\cos(y)+\cos(x))dy = 0$$
$$(\sin(y)-y\sin(x)) + (x\cos(y)+\cos(x))\color {red}{\dfrac {dy}{dx}} = 0$$
Regroup some terms:
$$\sin(y)-y\sin(x) + (x\cos(y)+\cos(x))y' = 0$$
$$ {\sin(y)}-\color {blue} {y\sin(x)} + \color {blue} {(\cos(x)y'}+{x(\sin y)')} = 0$$
$$\color{green}{\sin(y)} +\color {blue} { (\cos(x)y)'}+\color{green}{x(\sin y)' }= 0$$
$$\color {green} {(x\sin(y))'} + (\cos(x)y)' = 0$$
After integration:
$$x\sin(y) + \cos(x)y = C$$